# Should I commit or ignore Terraform local module symlinks?

Tags: git, version-control, terraform

Terraform may create a few files in a .terraform directory.

1. The .tfstate file, which is a json file containing the state. I can review this question for that.
2. .tfstate backups, which I'm pretty sure I can .gitignore.
3. The modules directory, which contains links to modules.

The `terraform get` command will create symlinks to my local module paths if I use [local modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html#local-file-paths). Those path names are hashes, like

```
7a1d2376c59a613c3888163f019b98c1@ -> /Users/michael/dev/a-project/terraform/modules/netpart
dc86adf2084ae95b189765d26b75702d@ -> /Users/michael/dev/a-project/terraform/modules/cluster
e03511e017c5612ae4b9e9ebc49d4611@ -> /Users/michael/dev/a-project/terraform/modules/cluster
eb8c48ae43e85626ff456d0a58a6a6a6@ -> /Users/michael/dev/a-project/terraform/modules/netpart
```

All these files are in the same repo. When a coworker cloned that repo, he noticed that running `terraform get` resulted in new symlinks, even though the modules had not changed.

Should I add the .terraform/modules directory to .gitignore and require all developers to run `terraform get` any time they `git pull`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We gitignore the whole `.terraform` folder entirely.

Yes it does mean you need to run a [`terraform get`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/get.html) before every action but typically when working as part of a team you will want to wrap your Terraform actions in helper scripts that can do this as well as managing remote state for you.

In fact the above documentation for `terraform get` explicitly advises you not to commit the folder to source control:

> The modules are downloaded into a local .terraform folder. This folder
>   should not be committed to version control.